# Why MySQL order by clause in window function creates cumulative sum?

Tags: mysql, window-functions

```
select orderNumber
     , priceEach
     , sum(priceEach) over(partition by orderNumber order by priceEach) as `running total`
     , sum(priceEach) over(partition by orderNumber) as `total`
from orderdetails;
```

From above query, why don't I get cumulative sum in `total` and cumulative some only when I add order by?

from https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/ 
order by clause is "The ORDER BY clause specifies how the rows are ordered within a partition" Even though rows are not ordered why does that stop us from getting cumulative sum?

Comment: Without an order by how could `sum` know which were the preceding rows to add up?

Comment: I'd thought since we partition by it should get simply continue to add rows values until another partition arise.

Comment: But it needs to know in which order to add them. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, row ordering is not guaranteed, so the "safe" thing for the DBMS to do is to add all rows as that guarantees a consistent result for the `SUM`.

Comment: understood! Thanks for clarifying

Comment: It's actually better explained in the [manual section on frames](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html), see the part after "In the absence of a frame clause, the default frame depends on whether an ORDER BY clause is present:"